# GRUB2 How to inspect which distros (and where) are installed on partitions?

Tags: linux

Old days are gone since it was simple to just view the `menu.lst` file... :)

How could I detect installations on partitions from command line in a fully-loaded system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` (on a BIOS system) or `/boot/EFI/<distro>/grub.cfg` (on UEFI systems).  On many systems, `/etc/grub2.cfg` is a symlink to one of the above.

You'll see `menuentry` for each menu entry followed by some module loading and then `linux` and `initrd` lines.  The latter two tell you where the kernel and initrd are located.

You could also use `os-prober` to scan disks for bootable partitions.